# Military/Government Breakdown in Post-Apocalyptic USSR

Tags: post-apocalypse, military, alternate-reality, nuclear, cold-war

***Background:***

In an alternative universe the Cold War (circa 1975) turns hot after some satellite communications errors. Nukes start flying — but for the purpose of the question, let's just focus on the Eastern part of the conflict, the USSR.

The consequences of the nuclear attack is that the USSR west of the Ural mountains is either destroyed or disrupted such that we can assume the area has been "wiped out." (Please accept this as a condition of the question. How it gets to this point is not relevant to the question. Only that no influence and/or help can come from west of the Urals.)

After the attack, what was left of the government and/or military on the east side of the Urals was waiting for some good news from the capital while weathering the crisis and the rising chaos.

In my story, Tashkent initially emerges from the chaos and starts claiming independence from the USSR. The remnants of the Soviet Union east of the Urals retreat to protect Omsk and Novosibirk. During this crisis, my protagonist takes over an oil refinery and slowly begins gaining control of factories and other industry. Eventually, he begins to raid areas around Tashkent.

***Question:***

What military and government disorganization (specifically: breakdowns) can be predicted for the major population centers east of the Ural mountains?

- USSR circa 1975.
- No communications, influence, or resources from west of the Urals.
- No passage through the USSR west of the Urals (all trade through the region is gone).

*This question is not asking for a timeline of events or the development of a story. It is only asking what disruptions, disorganization, or breakdowns could be expected in the event of a sudden loss of all primary government, trade, and military command from western USSR.*

Comment: So a strongman from the former Soviet Union (like a certain former KGB head) can't be your dictator? Read The Prince, by Machiavelli. A centralized authoritarian system is the easiest to dominate, because once the head is out of the way, the people seek a replacement or accept a conqueror.

Comment: I'm not ready to vote to close, but I'm close. Remember, worldbuilding is about rules and systems, storybuilding is about plot, circumstances, and character actions/choices. Right now this sounds an awful lot like storybuilding. You need to be *really specific* about asking a rule or system-based question. Such as, "If the USSR in 1978 suddenly lost everything west of the Urals to nuclear bombardment, what government and military disorganization would be expected east of the Urals?" Now, that question is ***really broad*** and would likely be opinion-based, but it wouldn't be story-based.

Comment: So, having said that... what's your question? (Remember, rule/system-based, specific and focused, etc.)

Comment: @JBH I think I’m just too bad at asking questions smh, can I edit to your question ? I think it would be helpful

Comment: @JBH Also please feel free to edit and save the question from being closed I’m stuck in the military part and really need some ideas and don’t really know how to formulate the question

Comment: @AimanVargas I've edited the question. If you don't like what I did, you can roll the question back to its previous version by clicking the "edited..." link above my name and to the left of your identifying block. My edits are based on a belief that you should ask two questions. The first, this one, gives you the info to "set the stage" for the second question. In other words, you learn what chaos you can take advantage of to "set the stage" for the leader's take-over of the oil field. Once you get some data from this question, if you still need help, you can then ask the second.

Comment: @JBH No I like it thanks a lot, I really appreciate your effort. I hope your magic will bring some answers lol.

Comment: The onvious "disruption" is that China will expand northwards taking what used to be called the Soviet Extreme Orient, that is, Primoriye and the entire eastern Siberia. Russia has never had all that many people there, and the balance of forces will be so severely disrupted that China will just walk in.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume that east of the Urals was not unscathed; if enough nukes are flying to utterly annihilate west of the Urals, surely some will target east of the Urals as well.  So the eastern USSR won't be pristine either.

With this in mind, empires collapse because local leaders realize the central government can't or won't intervene anymore.  They take it upon themselves to rule with as much authority as the old government did.  Some will be just, and do what they do to help their subordinates; others will just want more power and/or wealth.  Both kinds of leader will likely not get along with all of their neighbors.  "Georgiy one town over still has a working pharmacy, Ivan's people have typhus, but he has nothing to trade.  He's just going to have to take the medicine." and "Georgiy one town over still has a working pharmacy, if Ivan takes him over he'll have control of all the medicine within 50 miles." both end up the same.  Georgiy and Ivan do not get along.

How deep the breakdowns go depends on how screwed up communication and transportation get.  If the EMP's from the nukes burn up all the radio towers, a central leader can't coordinate anything.  If all the main roads and railroads are impassable, it doesn't even matter if you can communicate, you can't do anything about it anyways.  If you get an emergency radio message from 200 miles away, but the roads are all impassable, you can't help.  Leaders can only really rule a territory in which they can reasonably quickly detect and respond to threats.  How quick they can react depends on exactly how screwed up the transportation and communication networks are.  The more screwed up they are, the smaller a region someone could rule.  There's some wiggle room here as each ruler's neighbors are probably just as screwed up, so they'll have just as much trouble launching an attack as the defender will have responding.

Comment: Tanks for your answer! I think the USSR radio system would survive. The main roads and railroads to the west are obviously impassable but the eastern ones are still intact baring the civil war damage in the south.

Answer (score 2):

Look at four power centers: the party, the military, the secret police, and the civilian/economic administration.

- It was generally understood that the party was on top, certainly since Stalin's purges.
- Both the party and the secret police infiltrated the military and the administration -- perhaps the administration was more infiltrated than the military, with the [GRU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Intelligence_Directorate_(GRU)) trying to keep the [KGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KGB) out of the "military's home turf."
- KGB and party would interpenetrate each other, with loyalty to the party as a requirement for KGB service.

On paper, the party was loyal to an ideology, not to any one leader. In 1975 [Brezhnev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonid_Brezhnev) had been in power for one decade and presumably still healthy, yet he supposedly had a much more consensus-oriented style than his predecessors. Certainly the *party* did not want a repeat of the Stalinist reign of terror.

When the war happened, were any Politburo members in the eastern USSR? They might be well placed to assert control over the local KGB offices, and with them over the rest of the rump state. ("We must hang together or we will hang separately.")

If you want a balkanization, assume that there were local power struggles between the party and the secret police, with different outcome in different regions. Party men might be somewhat biased to work with party men, and agents might be biased to work with other agents.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think I should start some deep research on these USSR four powers organization and how they interact with each other, any sources you may propose? 
Also supposing I went with the balkanization, could you explain a little bit more how these local powers will emerge? Like what facilities would be taken by the party or the secret police and who the people will follow most?

Comment: @AimanVargas, read about Stalin, Beria, and Zhukov during and after WWII. Perhaps Montefiore, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalin:_The_Court_of_the_Red_Tsar

Comment: @AimanVargas, regarding the factions that will form, that is **your** story to write.

Answer (score 2):

For orientation (since these maps don't mark out the Urals), the Ural mountain range runs from Yuzhny island in the north, to between the Caspian and Aral seas in the south.

### Nearly All of Your Infrastructure (Roads and Railroads) is Pushed to the South

As shown in the image, east of Urals most of the roads and railroads concentrate along the southern border.

[image]

### Almost All of Your Population is Pushed South Also

Also, most ethnic Russians east of the Urals stick to the south There is a large population of other ethnic groups. However, for the most part, the country is sparsely populated.

[image]

### And Very Few People Remain

Here's a map of population concentration in the eastern Soviet Union. Almost all of the population is west of the Urals. What remains in the east (per the question) is very little.

[image]

### Mineral Resources Have Taken a Huge Hit

This map may just be developed natural resource harvesting. There may be more natural resources that haven't been prospected or developed.

[image]

### The Breadbasket is Mostly Gone

It looks like what's left of the land for agricultural use may be around ${1 \over 3}^{rd}$ the pre-apocalypse amount.

You have an extremely wide expanse of barely settled forest to the north.

[image]

Comment: Thank's a lot, not really what I was looking for but you just answered tons of other questions in my head! Based on these pieces of information do you think the two cities (Omsk and Novosibirk) will be able to run Oil Plants, Automotive industry and other complexes industries, and most importantly survive?

Comment: I’ll try to add more. I wasn’t certain what you were looking for in terms of breakdowns.